# jQuery events stop working with RxJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rxjs, livescript

So, basically, my problem is that at the start of my program, the jQuery `.css()` works just fine, tested by this:

```
$("#canvas").css("border", "3px solid red");
```

Just after that, when I try to add a div - which does indeed get added whenever it is required - `.css()` stops working for that element. Like this:

```
var elem = $("<div/>", {"class": "circle"});
elem.css({'background-color': color})
    .appendTo($("#circles"));
```

This just appends a `<div class="circle"></div>`, with no style and which can't later be `.remove()`'d-

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bh79fe87/

The full code looks like this (LiveScript):

```
O = Rx.Observable

## Extensions

Rx.Observable.repeatFunc = -> Rx.Observable.return null .map it .repeat!
Rx.Observable.prototype.scanCount = -> this.map 1 .scan 0 (+) .startWith 0

## Utils

write = (t, s) --> t.html t.html! + s + '<br />'

pairs-to-obj = -> {[p[0], p[1]] for p in it}

assoc = (m, t) -->
  for k, v of m
    if k of t then [k, t[k]]
              else [k, v]
  |> (++ [[k, v] for k, v of t if k not of m])
  |> pairs-to-obj

toLocal = (e, x, y) ->
  o = $(e).offset!
  {x: x - o.left, y: y - o.top}

## Game

createCircle = ->
  x = Math.random! * ($(canvas).width() - 20)
  y = -40 + Math.random! * 10
  color = ['#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF'][Math.floor Math.random! * 3]
  do
    x: x
    y: y
    color: color

createCircleStream = ($canvas, $circles) ->
  elem = $ '<div/>', class: 'circle'
  elemclicks = O.fromEvent elem, 'click'
    .map -> true
    .first!      # Kill the event after a click.
  stream = O.interval 16
    .scan createCircle!, (obj, click) -> assoc obj, y: obj.y + 1
    .takeWhile -> it.y < $canvas.height! + 1
  killstream = stream
    .filter -> it.y > $canvas.height!
    .merge elemclicks
    .map -> true
    .first!
  do
    clicks: elemclicks
    stream: stream
    kill: killstream
    elem: elem

$ ->
  $canvas = $ '#canvas'
  $hits = $ '#hits'
  $missclicks = $ '#missclicks'
  $misses = $ '#misses'
  $circles = $ '#circles'

  $canvas.css 'border', '3px solid red'

  # Events
  canvasclicks = O.fromEvent $canvas, 'click'
    .map -> toLocal canvas, it.pageX, it.pageY

  # Data streams
  circlestream = O.return 1 # O.repeatFunc -> createCircleStream $canvas, $circles
    .repeat!
    .controlled!

  circles = circlestream.map -> createCircleStream $canvas, $circles

  circleclicks = circles
    .flatMap (circle) ->
      circle.clicks
        .map -> circle

  circleupdates = circles
    .flatMap (circle) ->
      circle.stream
        .map -> assoc it, elem: circle.elem
        .takeUntil circle.kill

  circlekills = circles
    .flatMap (circle) ->
      circle.kill
        .map -> circle.elem

  hits = circleclicks.scanCount!
  missclicks = canvasclicks.scanCount!.combineLatest hits, (-)
  misses = circlekills.scanCount!.combineLatest hits, (-)

  # Side effects
  circles.subscribe ->
    it.elem.css 'background-color': it.color
           .appendTo $circles
    $('#canvas').css 'background-color': it.color

  circleupdates.subscribe ->
    it.elem.css do
      'left': it.x
      'top': it.y
      'background-color': it.color

  circlekills.subscribe ->
    it.remove!
    circlestream.request 1

  hits.subscribe       -> $hits.html "Hits: #it"
  missclicks.subscribe -> $missclicks.html "Missed clicks: #it"
  misses.subscribe     -> $misses.html "Missed circles: #it"

  # Kick off the game.
  circlestream.request 5
```

Also the HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>RxTest</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/rx.all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rxtest.js"></script>

        <style>
            #canvas {
                position: relative;
                width: 640px; height: 360px; background: #000000;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .game-container {
                position: absolute;
                background: transparent;
                color: #FFFFFF;
            }

            .circle {
                position: absolute;
                border-radius: 50%;
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="canvas">
            <div id="circles" class="game-container"></div>
            <div id="stats" class="game-container">
                <div id="hits"></div>
                <div id="missclicks"></div>
                <div id="misses"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check this fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/23Lutt76/

Comment: @jQuery I know it should work. But in my program, it just adds the empty div with no style.

Comment: yes . i thing you need to assign width and height of div?
i think problem with css not jquery code. check in console you will find added div?

Comment: @jQuery I indeed did check there and that's how I know the empty div gets added. I added the HTML & CSS to the question. `.circle` contains the width and height.

Comment: check this . http://jsfiddle.net/9vkdwzh3/
it is working .  may be you are not getting correct color code?

Comment: @jQuery All data flow is checked.

Comment: @jQuery Added a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/bh79fe87/

Comment: circles.subscribe(function(it){
      console.log(it.color);
        it.elem.css({
        'background-color': it.color
      }).appendTo($circles);
      return $('#canvas').css({
        'background-color': it.color
      });
    });
check this code .. here color is undefined

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bh79fe87/1/

i have pass static color and it working.?? pls check

Comment: check this

http://jsfiddle.net/bh79fe87/1/

Comment: @jQuery Apparently I missed the problem a little. I updated the following `circleupdates.subscribe`. Check it out. http://jsfiddle.net/4grpxxjs/

Comment: check may be this will work for you. ?
http://jsfiddle.net/4grpxxjs/1/

Comment: @jQuery Well, now it adds 300 circles / second.

Comment: Hope this will work for you ?
http://jsfiddle.net/4grpxxjs/2/

Comment: @jQuery Almost. Apparently the problem comes from keeping a reference to the circle. If I update it with `$("#circle-"+id).css` it works.

Comment: just as a heads up, `{x: x, y: y, color: color}` is `{x, y, color}` in LS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ookay, so, I was way off. Apparently, RxJS creates a new circle div for every subscriber. In this case, 4 event subscriptions were made for each circle. I solved this by using `Rx.Observable.prototype.publish()`.

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u3Lf6d26/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the $() in appendTo and just putting "#circles" there instead

Answer (score 0):

`class` is a reserved word in JavaScript (see: [ECMA-262 sec. 7.6.1.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1.2)) and using it probably stops your script from further execution. The are few ways to get around this. For example you can use `.addClass()` method to set your class.

Try changing this:

```
var elem = $("<div/>", {class: "circle"});
elem.css({'background-color': color})
    .appendTo($("#circles"));
```

to this:

```
var elem = $("<div/>").addClass("circle");
elem.css({'background-color': color})
    .appendTo($("#circles"));
```

and see if it helps.

Comment: That was just a typo in the question.

Comment: Also of note: the script works perfectly, disregarding rendering.

Comment: @Sieg Put your example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) or [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) so everyone can see what works and how. Giving limited info and making typos in the code in your question certainly don't help in diagnosing your problem. Posting live code example will probably get it solved in a minute.